# Install google chrome in Amazon linux EC2 instance - CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, chrome, amazon-ec2

I am currently facing troubles in installing google chrome/chromium in **Amazon EC2** instance.

I tried the command,

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXXX yum.repos.d]$ sudo yum install google-chrome-stable
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                                                                                                                                                  | 3.7 kB  00:00:00     
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/aarch64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
191 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
```

I have seen any solutions from stack overflow/other sites for this, but I nothing works and getting the same error. Some of them I tried are,

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623131/centos-unable-to-install-chromium-browser
2. [How to install Google Chrome on CentOS, Red Hat or Fedora](https://www.simplified.guide/google-chrome/install-on-centos-rhel)
3. [Unable to install Google Chrome on Linux](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3539851)

It looks like the repository is not found. It is true, as I get the same when I tried to access the link from the browser. As an alternative, I tried downloading the rpm and insatlled, but it seems to be a wrong architecture (but I thought its the same),

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXXX yum.repos.d]$ sudo wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
......
[ec2-user@ip-XXXX yum.repos.d]$ sudo yum install google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Examining google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm: google-chrome-stable-92.0.4515.107-1.x86_64
Cannot add package google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm to transaction. Not a compatible architecture: x86_64
Error: Nothing to do
```

Other information about the OS and repo are,

**/etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo**

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

**Os details**

```
[ec2-user@XXXX yum.repos.d]$ uname -m
aarch64
ec2-user@XXXX yum.repos.d]$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
[ec2-user@XXXX yum.repos.d]$ rpm -E %{rhel}
7
```

***Could someone please help on this?***

Comment: The (centos) command is `yum install chromium` ..... Please always do a search, e.g.  `yum search chrom`

Answer (score 2):

You are on an [ARM64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AArch64) (aarch64) system, Google doesn't provide repository for this architecture so you can't install Chrome from it. The RPM package you downloaded manually is for x86_64, you can't install it on ARM64, the error clearly says it:

> Cannot add package google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm to transaction. Not a compatible architecture: x86_64

One option would be to use Chromium, which is available in the EPEL repository, unfortunately [EPEL 7 is also not available for aarch64](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#What_packages_and_versions_are_available_in_EPEL.3F) so you'll unfortunately need to [build it yourself from source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md).

(I've updated my answer, the previous version was based on assumption that Amazon Linux is based on RHEL/CentOS 8 which has aarch64 EPEL, but as it seems to be based on RHEL/CentOS 7 which doesn't have aarch64 EPEL so using EPEL is not possible.)

Comment: Thank you @Vojtech Trefny. I tried the same and it mentions `No package chromium available.`. I used `epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm` because I got an error `Requires: redhat-release >= 8`

Comment: I've updated the answer, I thought Amazon Linux is based on RHEL 8, but it is based on RHEL 7 and EPEL 7 doesn't have aarch64 version so your only possibility seems to be building Chromium from source.